# Warum werden Sustantive mit Endung auf -ie unterschiedlich ausgesprochen: wie in "Historie" oder wie in "Amnesie"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

Als ich den mathematischen Begriff "Trajektorie" gelesen habe, bin ich davon ausgegangen, er werde am Ende mit langgezogenem "-i" ausgesprochen. Später habe ich herausgefunden, das Wort endet wie "Historie".
Gibt es die Schreibweise des Wortes oder durch dessen Herkunft begründet eine Regel, ob man ein Substantiv mit Endung auf "-ie" ausspricht wie "Historie" oder wie "Amnesie"?

Answer (score 6):

Zunächst kenne ich die Regel:

> Wörter, die auf *-ie* enden, werden genau dann am Ende mit langem *i* gesprochen, wenn ihre Betonung auf der ersten oder letzten Silbe liegt.

Bei zusammengesetzen Wörtern verändert sich die Betonung natürlich nicht, sondern richtet sich nach dem Ursprungswort.

Zur Herkunft:
Wörter, die auf *-ie* enden, stammen aus dem Lateinischen oder Griechischen. Nun hängt es davon ab, wie sie in die deutsche Sprache gelangten.

Wurde das Wort aus dem Französischen übernommen, sie wurde die Betonung an den Anfang oder das Ende des Wortes gelgt und die Aussprache blieb wie im Französichen: als langes *i*.

Wurde das Wort direkt aus den alten Sprachen, oder aber aus dem Italienischen oder Spanischen übernommen, so wurde die Aussprache an das alte *-ia* bzw. an die italienische und spanische Aussprache von *-ie* angepasst: [i][e]

Comment: Interessant so weit. Wie aber fügt sich hier die "Trajektorie" hinein, die auch für mich überraschend nun angeblich mit i--e, nicht einfach langem i zu sprechen sein soll? Denn wenn man sie als "Trajektoriiii" spricht, ist die Betonung ja eh hinten, insofern ist dann die oben zitierte Regel eigentlich zirkulär... oder?

Comment: Trajekt**o**rie wird auch auf *o* betont, also passt sie in das Schema. Ich denke, dass dir die Regel zirkulär vorkommt, da du sie so verinnerlicht hast.  Denn man könnte ja durchaus "Trajekt**o**riiii" sagen, es hört sich aber eben falsch an. Da wir eben mit genau dieser Regel unterbewusst betonen.

Comment: Klar, ich habe "Trajektoriiii" verinnerlicht, und darum hört sich für mich "Trajektooori-e" falsch an. Ist natürlich einfach eine Frage der Gewohnheit. Aber damit ist die Regel eben doch zirkulär. Die Regel sagt ja: "Wenn Betonung auf erster oder letzter Silbe, dann Aussprache mit iiiii (sonst i-e)." Wenn ich nun die Betonung auf die letzte Silbe lege, ist die Aussprache eben "iiii", nicht "i-e". Das heißt doch, die Regel hilft nicht weiter beim Finden der "korrekten" Aussprache. Oder?

Comment: Du hast natürlich irgendwie Recht: die Regel hilft nur, wenn man die korrekte *Betonung* kennt, um die *Aussprache* zu finden, oder wenn man die korrekte *Aussprache* kennt, um die *Betonung* zu finden. Ist man sich bei beidem nicht sicher, hilft wohl nur noch der Duden...

Comment: Ich glaube, ich habe das Wort einfach noch nie von jemandem (oder jemandem mit Aussprachekompetenz) gehört sondern es immer nur gelesen. Gibt es hier jemanden, in dessen z.B. beruflichen Umfeld regelmäßig das Wort *Trajektorie* vorkommt und der aus der Aussprachepraxis seines Metiers berichten könnte? Ein Raumfahrer vielleicht?

Comment: Also ich kann aus der Uni berichten, dort wird es in Mathematik, Physik und Ingenieurswissenschaften definitiv "Trajekt**o**r[i][e]" ausgesprochen, wie auch im Duden angegeben: https://www.duden.de/_media_/audio/ID4190020_250537087.mp3

Comment: Vielen Dank, RoyPJ, das klingt dann ja nach einem Wortnutzerkreis, der weiß, wovon er spricht - und wie es auszusprechen ist.

Comment: Möglicherweise stammt die irrige Annahme daher, dass man das gleichlautende englische Wort "Trajectory" ähnlich ausspricht.

Answer (score 5):

Ich halte fest, dass die getrennte Aussprache viel seltener ist, weil es ganze Zusammensetzungsbündel gibt, in denen das lange i gefragt ist: -logie, -graphie, meist kommt das Wort aus dem Griechischen und endet dort -εɩα.

Die Regel aus der anderen Antwort überzeugt mich nicht, weil es zu viele Gegenbeispiele gibt:

> Aktie, Arie, Hostie, Knie (Plural), Lilie, Linie, Prämie, Serie, Studie

Meine Erklärung: es gibt im Deutschen keine andere Darstellung für diese Lautkombination, *iä* sieht zu fremdartig aus.

Andererseits gibt es auch keinen Anspruch darauf, Buchstaben ohne Kenntnis des Kontexts korrekt aussprechen zu können, nur weil es im Deutschen sonst oft funktioniert.

Und schließlich bezweifle ich, dass es sich bei zumindest bei meinen Beispielen überhaupt um eine Endung handelt.

Comment: Das sind wirklich einige Beispiele, die ich nicht bedacht habe. Vielleicht gibt es eine andere Regel für Wörter mit weniger als drei Silben? Diese werden in den allermeisten Fällen mit [i][e] ausgesprochen.. Als Gegenbeispiel fällt mir widerum *Manie* ein. Das könnte allerdings auch eine Ausnahme sein?

Comment: Das ist einfach historisch gewachsene Inkonsequenz, so wie `Gras` und `Spaß` unnötig unterschiedlich geschrieben werden trotz gleicher Betonung. Konsequent wäre eine Schreibweise wie in `Hawaii`, aber welche Sprache hat je alte Zöpfe abgeschnitten?